# 5GHZ wifi is not showing on fresh install

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I'm new to Linux. Apple stopped supporting my laptop (early 2011 Macbook pro 15) so I'm looking to join the linux family.

My laptop has a Broadcom BCM4331 2 band wireless card. It's this one...

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)

I can access 2G and 5G bands fine on my OSX installation but on Linux I can only see the 2G option. I followed this guide...

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

I followed answer 404, the lengthy one. On a previous installation I had 5G and 2g networks showing on Linux without a problem. But I had to re-install linux due to some issues and now I can only see the 2G option.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Would appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, so in my research I replaced Ubuntu with Debian and found
https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple/MacBookPro/9-2
While it is not your and my MacBookPro version, it does the trick

```bsh
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) && sudo apt install -y broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms
```

then reboot

`reboot`

Comment: Works for MacBook Pro 8,2 (2010 vintage) with B43 4331 running Buster (10.10)